# iOS simulator trying to access keyboard cache

Tags: caching, ios5, keyboard

I'm getting these weird logs while developing my app. It happens when the on-screen keyboard is appearing on screen.

```
AppName[1001:f803] Opening '/Users/me/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Library/Caches/com.apple.keyboards/images/1859589221' failed: 'No such file or directory' (2)
AppName[1001:f803] 'INSERT INTO store VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)' constraint failed (19)
```

Both logs appear simultaneously. And my app doesn't use core data or sqlite.

Any idea why this happen? Can I just ignore them? Should I?

Answer (score 1):

@soemarko ridwan

Try looking at [Baffled by what to do to fix these errors (iOS)...any suggestions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10951770/baffled-by-what-to-do-to-fix-these-errors-ios-any-suggestions)

You may need to clear your iOS simulator cache for your keyboard.

Try deleting the `/Users/your-user-name/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Library/Caches/com.apple.keyboards` directory and build again.

Obviously you will need to replace 'your-user-name', and '5.1' with the version of iOS your targeting on your simulator.

Comment: my problem seems to fix itself, maybe the cache expires. My app didn't crash and burn like the one you linked to, but I will try this if it happens again.